# Applets not working with java 1.8 u91 and Firefox 45

Tags: applet

After updating Java to 1.8 u91 .. the applets are not working with Firefox 45. The applets are launched but their method can't be invoked by javascript ( xxx()  is not a function )

I have tested on IE and they works well.

Answer (score 3):

As you can read in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html):

> Because it might cause the browser to hang, we don't process
> JavaScript-to-Java calls when the Java plugin is launched from
> plugin-container.exe (the default behavior for Firefox 42) and the
> applet status is not Ready(2). If the applet is not ready (the status
> is not 2), we don't execute the actual Java method and only return
> null.
>
> If the plugin is launched from plugin-container.exe, do not use
> JavaScript-To-Java calls that may require more than 11 seconds(the
> default value of dom.ipc.plugins.hangUITimeoutSecs) to be completed or
> show a modal dialog during JavaScript-To-Java call. In this case, the
> main browser thread must be blocked, which might cause the browser to
> hang and the plugin to terminate.
>
> Workaround (for Firefox 42): User’s can set
> dom.ipc.plugins.enabled=false. The side effect of this workaround is
> that it changes the setting for all plugins.

Please note that this is true for higher firefox version as well...

Comment: This says, "... and the applet status is not Ready". But that implies rather strongly that eventually the applet should become "Ready" and the functions accessible. Such is not (apparently) the case.

Answer (score -1):

Dont call the applet from JS, call JS from the applet. 
IE writte a callstack that is beeing filled by JS and beeing polled by the applet periodically. 
This brings in some little delays, but clears the liveconnect issues.